# не получается получить JSON через POST запрос на стороне REST сервиса

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

У меня есть контроллер RESTController запущенный на Jetty сервере.
От клиента посылаю POST с JSON

```
{
  "name":"Vlad"
}
```

ошибка на стороне сервера при получении JSON

```
package controller;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpTester.Request;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("SOMEADDRESS")
public class RESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "initiateAuthentication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String initiateAuthentication(@RequestBody User user) {
        return "initiateAuthentication received";
    }


}
```

=================================

```
package controller;

public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Ошибка на строне сервера:

```
2016-10-14 14:14:38 WARN  o.e.j.s.ServletHandler:552 - 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference;)Z
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519) [jetty-servlet-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:446) [jetty-servlet-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:269) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229) [jetty-server-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) [jetty-io-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) [jetty-util-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) [jetty-util-9.0.6.v20130930.jar:9.0.6.v20130930]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Comment: Укажите ошибку, которая возникает, ну и код ошибки(ответа) тоже.

Comment: на стороне клиента:<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /SMDPIP/initiateAuthentication. Reason:
<pre>    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference;)Z</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Очень похоже на несовместимость версий спринга и десериализатора. Попробуй версию fasterXML   2.8.1 и более низкие. Ну и вопрос: другие запросы с json работают?